# What is different ways to prove that $\sqrt p$ is irrational when $p$ is prime?

Tags: big-list, irrational-numbers, alternative-proof

I know this fact can be proved by contradiction (reductio ad absurdum) but please give proofs by different methods.

Comment: you mean no proof by 'reductio ad absurdum'?

Comment: Let $\sqrt{p}=a/b$ with integers $a$, $b$.  Then $a^2=b^2p$.  Now $a^2$ has an even number of prime factors, whereas $b^2p$ has on odd number of them.

Comment: If $x_0$ is a rational solution of $x^2+ax+b=0$ with integers $a$, $b$ then $x_0$ must be an integer.  Now consider $x^2-p=0$.

Comment: Look at this too: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/32011/direct-proof-of-irrationality

Comment: @MichaelHoppe your first comment is by contradiction.  Your second comment is not specific in this respect.  How do you prove the rational root theorem?

Comment: I'm a bit curious: what's your problem with the proofs by a contradiction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By [Eisenstein's criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion), the polynomial $x^2-p$ is irreducible.

(To answer WimC's complaint below: Consider the splitting field of $x^2-p$ over $\mathbf Q_p$. It contains an element of valuation $1/2$, so it is a proper over-field of $\mathbf Q_p$, and therefore $x^2-p$ is irreducible over $\mathbf Q_p$ (and a fortiori over $\mathbf Q$)).

Comment: Unfortunately, that link proves Eisenstein's criterion by contradiction, so in this form it is not an answer to the question.

Answer (score 3):

If $\sqrt p$ is rational then there are whole numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $\sqrt p = \frac{a}{b}$, where $a > 0$ and $b > 0$ and they are co-primes, i.e. there is no prime that divides both. (If there is, then divide $a$ and $b$ by that number and get a new $a$ and $b$ that meet this criterion).

Then $\large p = \frac{a^2}{b^2}$ and then $\large\frac{pb^2}{a^2} = 1$.
Since $a$ cannot divide $b$ then $p$ is divisible by $a$  which makes $p$ non-prime.

Answer (score 2):

By Gauss's lemma, any rational root of $x^2-p$ must be an integer.

But by unique factorization, $p$ cannot be the square of an integer.

Answer (score 2):

By Dirichlet's theorem on primes in arithmetic progressions and by quadratic reciprocity (!!), there exists a prime $\ell$ such that $$\left(\frac{p}{\ell}\right) = -1.$$

By Gauss's lemma, any rational root of $x^2−p$ must be an integer. But if $p$ were the square of an integer, it would certainly be a square mod $\ell$ also. Thus, $x^2-p$ has no rational root.

Comment: All this has a hidden proof by contradiction part. Because it is based on showing that $\sqrt p$ is not rational and not that it is irrational. isn't it?

Comment: @Arash What would be the difference between "not rational" and "irrational"?

Comment: @WimC, What I want to say is that at some point, one has to assume that if $\sqrt p$ is rational then we get a contradiction. So the irrationality is proved by proving that something is not rational.

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind the proof is that if $\sqrt p$ is rational then it should be integer. Until here that is not a proof by contradiction.

However afterward, we have to assume that if $\sqrt p$ is rational then it is integer and then it is impossible for $\sqrt p$ to be integer and hence contradiction. So it is still a proof by contradiction.

---

**Now the proof:**

First of all observe that because $p$ is prime there is no natural number $x>1$ such that $x^2=p$ otherwise $x\mid p$ for $x<p$.

Secondly if there are $x,y\in\mathbb N$, such that $(x,y)=1$, and $x^2=py^2$, then we have:
$$
\frac xy=\sqrt p\implies \frac{py}x=\sqrt p
$$
Note that $py> x$, $y>1$. Write $x=q_0y+r_0$ where $y>r_0>0$. $r_0$ cannot be zero otherwise $\sqrt p=q_0$ which we saw that is not possible.

Now we can write:
$$
\frac xy= \frac{py}x=\sqrt p\implies\frac{py-q_0x}{x-q_0y}=\sqrt p
$$

Now we found another fraction with $0<r_0=x-q_0y<y$, which means a fraction with a smaller denominator. Now take $\frac{y_0}{r_0}=\frac{py-q_0x}{r_0}$ and $\frac xy$, and write $y=q_1r_0+r_1$. Again $r_1\neq 0$ because otherwise $r_0\mid y$ and $r_0\mid x$ and hence $\frac{y_0}{r_0}$ would be a natural number which is not possible. Therefore $r_1>0$.

Using the same procedure we find $y_1$ and $r_1<r_0$ such that $\frac{y_1}{r_1}=\sqrt p$. By continuing like this we find sequence of $y_n$ and $r_n$ such that $r_0>r_1>\dots>r_n>\dots>0$ which means that eventually we should arrive to $r_n=1$ for some $n$ and hence $\sqrt p=y_n$ which is not possible.

Comment: Looks to me as a reductio ad absurdum ...

Comment: Look at the answer, I told it at the very beginning.